# is there any reason to leave ref to System.Runtime.CompilerServices in AssemblyInfo.cs?

Tags: c#, resharper, using

I just started using resharper and it barks at this generated assemblyinfo.cs file.

Reason/Logic tells me I'm fine to take the line out because it's the latest version of resharper and it's a popular tool.

My worry is something along the lines of my limited understanding w.s.t. interactions of newer c# features like extension methods in combination with taking a "using" out that appears to not be "used".

Hope that made some sense.

Here's the screen shot for clarity's sake.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `newer C# features`, you can safely remove it.

Comment: am i wrong that "using" interacts with selection of extension methods? is it a safe bet that resharper would have already taken it into account?

Comment: Yes, it interacts. `System.Linq` should be in `using` section in order to Linq extension methods start working. But Resharper takes it into account so if it says that this `using` can be removed then it can be removed. It is very rare case when Resharper says `remove` and removing breaks something and those cases should be added to resharper bug tracker.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why this assembly is seemingly _always_ included in AssemblyInfo and _never_ needed?  I say seemingly because I obviously haven't authored every assembly ever created, but every time I've run ReSharper's "Remove unused directives in solution" command, the CompilerServices assembly is removed from this file.